# SQL grouping results in a select

Tags: sql

My SQL table "offers" contains offers users make for products (product_ID, customer_ID, offer).

In my admin page, I want to list the products for which at least one offer exists and show the total offers existing for it.

For example,

```
PRODUCT #324     Total offers: 42
PRODUCT #99      Total offers: 1
etc.
```

My guess would be to combine a
`SELECT DISTINCT product_ID FROM offers...`
And in a second query, to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM offers WHERE product_ID=...`

Is it the most efficient way to achieve this, or is there a way to make it inside a single query?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one query which will get the count by grouping by the `product_id`:

```
SELECT product_ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM offers 
GROUP BY product_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

As bluefeet already answered, you achieve it in single query by using group by.
[(group by demo)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Another thing to mention is the order by,

```
select
  product_id as id,
  count(*) as totals
from 
  t
group by product_id
order by totals;
```

If you want to sort with the totals of hits, or if you want to sort by product_id etc.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6adc/6)

Comment: Thanks for the additionnal info